# Rename the Project in VS 2008 from C#

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

VS 2008 : ASP.Net

My Project Solution file name is abc ..
So, when i run the application - it shows http://localhost/abc/login.aspx

But i need to rename the project as ..http://localhost/Reports/login.aspx

Without changing the folder / solution file or creating a new project .. is there any way for me to set it in the config file for changing the project name !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the start page in your web project **Properties** -> **Web** tab. There you can choose **"Specific Page"** as the **Start Action** and type for example "Reports/login.aspx" there.

Whether this URL will be served by your application correctly is another issue (if you use MVC routing mechanism, and I guess you do if you tagged the question with asp.net-mvc, you may have to check if one of your routes handles this particular URL).

Comment: This project is developed on VS 2008. Yes, i need something like routing mechnism, which will rename the URL